# Postgres Increment JSONB Object Property By X

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following JSONB object in column "charges" of table "Reservation".

```
{"total": 0, "charges": [{"foo": "bar"}]}
```

What's the SQL statement to increment (update) the value of total by X without modifying rest of the JSONB structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample and query structure in: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c282ca7939ecddc07610c4826a5b10c1)

```sql
select
  data as before,
  data || jsonb_build_object('total', (data ->> 'total') :: numeric + 3) as after
from
  test
```

Or if you want update table you can use this sample:

```sql
update your_table
set your_josnb_column = your_josnb_column || jsonb_build_object('total', (your_josnb_column ->> 'total') :: numeric + 3)
```

Comment: Updated my question to be more precise, can you answer again, apologies!

Comment: Please check it was correct? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7d6128e34a922c8e422668ce8f2a3207